# Bind values to DB::raw for UPDATE

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, eloquent

I want to bind values to a `DB::raw(...)` query part, but only for an **UPDATE**, so I don't want neither `select(DB::raw('...'), [...])` nor `whereRaw('...', [...])` nor `setBindings([...])`.

For example, I want to be able to bind values to the following `DB::raw`:

```
$user = User::find(3);
$newCoordinates = ['coordinates' => DB::raw("GeomFromText('POINT(:lat :lng)')")];
$user->update($newCoordinates);
```

If it doesn't work for the `update()` function, is there a way to do it for the `save()` function?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can manually add bindings but in the cases of floats and integers, I wouldn't bother.  Just cast* lat and lng to a float and insert them directly into  the raw expression.

Comment: @Devon You might be right, I already have validation rules to check the coordinates (`required|numeric|min:-85|max:85` for latitude and `required|numeric|min:-180|max:180` for longitude) and I even put the whole code in a try/catch block.

Comment: Do you use/need the `updated_at` timestamp?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Yes, but I changed its name. I assume you would have told me to retrieve the PDO instance and use it?

Comment: You write that you don't want `setBindings()`: Do you not want to use it (why?) or do you think that you can't use it?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir When I saw people use `setBindings` it was always for SELECT queries. I also tried `DB::raw('...')->setBindings([...])` but it didn't work. I think that I can't use it in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Not very elegant, but it works:

```
$user = User::find(3);
$newCoordinates = ['coordinates' => DB::raw("GeomFromText('POINT(?, ?)')")];
$user->newQuery()->setBindings([$lat, $lng], 'join')
    ->whereKey($user->id)->update($newCoordinates);
```

If you want to update more attributes, you have to add them after `'coordinates'`.