# SQL injection in Laravel 10

Tags: sql, laravel, database, code-injection

I have codes see below which is works.

```
$city = City::find(1);
$city->location = DB::raw('geomfromtext(\'point(' . $location . ')\')');
$city->save();
```

Question 1:
Is there SQL injection issue in the codes above because I using DB::raw() which sticking the string(variable) in without processing ?

Question 2:
If yes, there is SQL injection issue in the codes, how to bind the variables into DB::raw()?

Thanks

I tried below.

```
DB::connection('datadb')->table('city')->where('id', '=', $profile->id)->update(['location' => DB::raw("(GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(54.8765696 -2.9261824)'))")]);
```

It works, but if I try to do like below. It failed.

$location = '54.8765696 -2.9261824';
DB::connection('datadb')->table('city')->setBindings([$location, $profile->id])->whereRaw('id = ?')->update(['location' => DB::raw("(GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(?)'))")]);

I got the error "*SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (Connection: datadb, SQL: update `city` set `location` = (GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(-33.742612777347 151.27899169922)')) where id = 1126)"*"

But the query "*update city set location = (GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(-33.742612777347 151.27899169922)')) where id = 1126;*" definitely works.

I did lots of research but looks most of answers relate to selectRaw, whereRaw, groupbyRaw... in Laravel. No anyone saying when we do the update and insert how to bind the parameters in DB::raw().

Similar question like this [Binding parameter to Db::raw laravel query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41913973/binding-parameter-to-dbraw-laravel-query) but not answer my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binding parameter to Db::raw laravel query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41913973/binding-parameter-to-dbraw-laravel-query)

Comment: See also [Bind values to DB::raw for UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741366/bind-values-to-dbraw-for-update)

Answer (score 0):

1. Laravel's orm(eloquent) prevents sql injections, **but not with raw()**
2. $city->location = DB::raw('geomfromtext(\'point(':location')\')', ['location ' => $location]); is how you bind variables in eloquent

Comment: First, thanks for your comment. But your solution doesn't work. I can see the raw query is like "update city set location = geomfromtext('point(:location)') where id = 1126" from the DB log which means DB::raw doesn't support bind variables I think.

Comment: @Johnson this seems strange, I use it like that, but perhaps the laravel versions differ, you can try with $city->location = DB::raw('geomfromtext(\'point(':location')\')', ['location ' => $location]);

Comment: or remove array from the query althogether and use ->setBindings([$location]) before ->save();

Comment: both failed. I can see the parameter doesn't bind to raw(). update city set location = geomfromtext('point(:location)') where id = 1126

Comment: try with $city->location = DB::raw('geomfromtext(\'point(?)\')', [$location]);

Comment: tried, no error, but it doesn't update the data. the raw query I can see from the DB log is "**update `city` set `location` = geomfromtext('point(?)') where `id` = 1126**" which means DB::raw() doesn't support bind parameters.

Answer (score 0):

What docs say about [**raw** expressions/methods](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#raw-methods):

> Raw statements will be injected into the query as strings, so you should be extremely careful to avoid creating SQL injection vulnerabilities.

and

> Laravel can not guarantee that any query using raw expressions is protected against SQL injection vulnerabilities.

A [tip](https://github.com/LaravelDaily/laravel-tips/blob/master/db-models-and-eloquent.md#remember-to-use-bindings-in-your-raw-queries) is that you can pass an array of bindings to most raw query methods to avoid SQL injection:

```
// This is vulnerable to SQL injection
$fullname = request('full_name');
User::whereRaw("CONCAT(first_name, last_name) = $fullName")->get();

// Use bindings
User::whereRaw("CONCAT(first_name, last_name) = ?", [request('full_name')])->get();
```

You can send [raw query to update](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/database#running-an-update-statement) like this (because `->getValue(DB::connection()->getQueryGrammar())` returns a string with the SQL) and still use the binds as in docs with `DB::update()`:

```
$expression = DB::raw('UPDATE city SET location = (GEOMFROMTEXT(POINT(?))) WHERE id = ?')->getValue(DB::connection()->getQueryGrammar());

DB::update($expression, [$location, $id]);
```

And for inserts, is the same, just use:
`DB::insert($expression, [$location, $id]);`

This `getValue()` was implemented in L10 [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/upgrade#database-expressions).

Comment: Yes, from the document we can see most of function like selectRaw, whereRaw and groupByRaw work with select statement only. How about update and insert function ?

Comment: @Johnson check the solution I have presented to you

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried the code below. It still failed. (But the query 'UPDATE city SET location = (GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(-33.742612777347 151.27899169922)')) WHERE id = 1126' definitely works, not sure what's happened.).   **$expression = DB::raw('UPDATE investor SET location = (GEOMFROMTEXT(\'POINT(?)\')) WHERE id = ?')->getValue(DB::connection('datadb')->getQueryGrammar());

        DB::connection('datadb')->update($expression, [$location, $profile->id]);**

Comment: The error message is **"message": "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (Connection: datadb, SQL: UPDATE city SET location = (GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(-33.742612777347 151.27899169922)')) WHERE id = 1126)",
    "exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",**

Comment: look, from [this](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3702), it says that in MySQL 8.0 and higher doesn't recognize `GeomFromText` function (deprecated). U sure isn't that?

Comment: TLDR: use named binds like `:id` instead of `?` and on bind param do `['id' => 1126]`, probaby the `?` are confused in the query..

Comment: Tried this **$expression = DB::raw('UPDATE investor SET location = (GEOMFROMTEXT(\'POINT(:location)\')) WHERE id = :id')->getValue(DB::connection('datadb')->getQueryGrammar());
        DB::connection('datadb')->update($expression, ['location' => $location, 'id' => $profile->id]);** and failed again with error "message": "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined (Connection: datadb, SQL: UPDATE investor SET location = (GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(:location)')) WHERE id = :id)","

Comment: My DB version is 11.0.3-MariaDB-1:11.0.3+maria~ubu2204-log and the query "UPDATE city SET location = (GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(-33.742612777347 151.27899169922)')) WHERE id = 1126;" works in my DB console.

Comment: look [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33410/whats-the-difference-between-pointx-y-and-geomfromtextpointx-y) they say: "Skipping the history lesson, NEVER do GeomFromText(Point(x,y)). That's horrible, unsupported, and undocumented."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, finally I found one solution how to update the location field (Point type) via Laravel eloquent modal. https://github.com/MatanYadaev/laravel-eloquent-spatial

But still not answer my original question - how to binds parameter with Laravel eloquent modal when we do update or insert with function DB::raw().

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).